Excel how to put value in certain place and fill the rest

If the value is 9 then I put Albert at 9 and Betty at 1, and the rest people on 2-8 accordingly. If I change the value to 6 then Albert at 6, Betty at 7.
How should I write this formula?
I tried to use vlookup and if but can't resolve the circulation problem.

=INDEX(D1:L1,,XMATCH(B4:B12,MOD(SEQUENCE(9,,B2-1),9)+1))

Where D1:L1 are the names,
B4:B12 # 1 to 9 and
B2 your start number.

The formula works but do you know why i returned "spill" sometimes

Spill error is typical for the result of the formula overlapping a cell containing data already. All cells where the result of the formula is expected need to be cleared, or you'll receive this error.

@P.b Sir, i think it might help OP, if you add the older version as well!

I see the row wise equivalent of my post is already posted by @BlackCat

This formula
=INDEX(E$1:M$1,1,MOD(9+A4-$B$1,9)+1)
results like this:

